How to implement live streaming in a Telegram bot?
I am trying to implement a live streaming feature in my Telegram bot but am not sure where to start. Specifically, I want to stream a live video/audio feed to the users who interact with my bot.
I understand that Telegram supports sending various types of media, including videos and voice notes, but I couldn't find clear documentation or examples on live streaming directly through a bot.
Here are my questions:

Does the Telegram Bot API support live streaming?
If so, how can I implement it using Python or any other language?
Are there any specific libraries, services, or protocols (e.g., WebRTC, RTMP) that need to be integrated?
Are there any limitations or restrictions I should be aware of regarding bandwidth or duration for streams in Telegram bots?

Any code examples, suggestions, or documentation references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!


Does the Telegram Bot API support live streaming?

It does not.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api lists all available functionality.
